# Do I have to set parent when set post term?

Tags: terms

When save a term which is a child term, if I don't provide specific parent id, will WP make this term's parent 0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a term for a hierarchical taxonomy, if you don't specify a parent, its parent ID is set to 0. In other words, it becomes a parent term.

---

Edited with regards to comments:

- Add specifically each term you wish to add to the post (parent terms aren't automatically added if their children are).
- Adding terms to posts does not effect the terms relationship with each other (i.e.. child-parent relationship remains in tact).

Comment: the term already created as a child of another term. Now I want to assign the child to a post.

Comment: so you want to know if you need to provide the ID of the taxonomy term's parent along with the child term? Do you want to add both child and parent terms to the post?

Comment: I want to add child term to the post, not care the parent being added or not, but want the child term's parent always be the same.

Comment: Edited my answer - does that answer your question? :)